I'm trying to make a custom "loadable" builtin for Bash, but I keep getting a segmentation fault
I'm trying to make a "loadable" Bash builtin that can be enabled using the enable command. This builtin will use lseek to allow changing the byte offset of a file descriptor.
The end goal here is being able to rewind a file descriptor by 1 byte and to do so extremely fast (say, less than 100 μs). For this particular application the time it would take to call an external binary to implement this is too long, but I think/hope that a loadable builtin will be sufficiently fast.
I am able to create the shared dynamically loaded library file and can load it with enable -f ./lseek lseek, but when I try to use it I just get a segmentation fault (core dumped) error.
The lseek.c source code as well as the commands I'm using to compile it are shown in the script below.
NOTE: I have very little knowledge of C. The lseek.c source code is originally from ChatGPT, and then I tried my best to modify it using the example loadables and this guide, and sorta just tweaked stuff until it compiled and loaded. The compile commands are based off of what make runs to compile the other example loadables.
If anyone can see what the error is and tell me how to correct it I'd much appreciate it.

My env

OS: Fedora 40
Bash: 5.2.x

Build the loadable
git clone https://git.savannah.gnu.org/git/bash.git

cd bash

./configure

cd ./examples/loadables

cat<<'EOF' >lseek.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include "command.h"
#include "builtins.h"

int 
builtin_lseek (list)
WORD_LIST *list; {

    // Check for the right number of arguments
    if (list == NULL || list->word->word == NULL || list->next->word->word == NULL || list->next->next->word->word != NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: lseek <fd> <offset>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Extract arguments from WORD_LIST
    char *fd_str = list->word->word;
    char *offset_str = list->next->word->word;

    int fd = atoi(fd_str);  // Convert the first argument to integer (file descriptor)
    off_t offset = atoll(offset_str);  // Convert the second argument to long long (offset)

    if (fd < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid file descriptor: %d\n", fd);
        return 1;
    }

    off_t new_offset = lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_CUR);  // Use SEEK_CUR to move relative to current position
    if (new_offset == (off_t) -1) {
        perror("lseek");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("File descriptor %d moved to offset %lld\n", fd, (long long)new_offset);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}


char *lseek_doc[] =
{
  "Change file descriptor offset",
  "",
  "Changes the byte offset of the file descriptor relative to the current byte offset",
  "--> 1st input is file descriptor number (non-negative integer)",
  "--> 2nd input is relative byte offset (non-zero integer)",
  "",
  "Specifying a positive byte offset will advance the file descriptor",
  "Specifying a negative byte offset will rewind the file descriptor",
  (char *)NULL
};


struct builtin lseek_struct = {
    "lseek",   /* command name */
    builtin_lseek,      /* function implementing the builtin */
    BUILTIN_ENABLED,        /* initial flags for builtin */
    lseek_doc,              /* array of long documentation strings. */
    "lseek <fd> <rel_offset>",     /* usage synopsis; becomes short_doc */
    0                       /* reserved for internal use */
};
EOF

gcc -fPIC -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -DSHELL   -g -O2 -Wno-parentheses -Wno-format-security -I. -I.. -I../.. -I../../lib -I../../builtins -I. -I../../include -c -o lseek.o lseek.c
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,lseek  -I /usr/include/bash -o lseek lseek.o 

Test the loadable
enable -f ./lseek lseek

(
  mapfile -t -n 11 -u $fd A
  lseek $fd 1; read -r -u $fd B
  printf '%s\n' "${A[@]}"; echo; echo; echo $B
) {fd}<./lseek.c

Test result
Segmentation fault (core dumped)


Your basic function definition syntax is wrong. It's using the original K&R syntax, which is still supported for legacy reasons, but should not be used in new code (it's being removed completely in the next version of the C standard). Don't let AI write your code for you if you don't know what you're doing.

Run your bash under a debugger and find out which line exactly causes segfault. Alternatively add more printf for debuging. I wonder if to seek fd you could use dd if=/dev/fd/fd seek=1 count=0. I wiuld guess that list->next is null, you null check looks odd overall, why doesn't it check every single pointer, but just jumps to next word word word.

If you want "extremely fast", shell is not the appropriate choice.

This check is buggy:
if (list == NULL || list->word->word == NULL || list->next->word->word == NULL || list->next->next->word->word != NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: lseek <fd> <offset>\n");
    return 1;
}

With lseek <fd> <offset>, only list (the fd) and list->next (the  offset) are available so list->next->next would be NULL and list->next->next->word->word causes the segfault.
You can just change it to:
if (list == NULL || list->next == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: lseek <fd> <offset>\n");
    return 1;
}

I tried and the lseek loadable works fine with this change.

And it's good practice to declare internal functions/vars as static:
static int builtin_lseek( ...

static char *lseek_doc[] = ...


It seems like this would only result in a segfault if they gave too few arguments, not in the example they tried. It certainly should be fixed, but I don't think it's the reason for their error.

@Barmar with lseek <fd> <offset> only list and list->next are available but OP is also checking list->next->next. i tried myself and it worked fine after fixing the if statement.

Thank you for this. I was admittedly quite confused with the list ->next->word type of syntax, so it doesnt surprise me this was the issue.
I was able to figure out another solution (added as an answer to this post) on my own that uses the internal bash make_builtin_argv() function to convert the list to standard argc and argv inputs, though am concerned that a free(v) call that I removed to avoid a "missing sh_xfree symbol" error might cause issues.
Ill try out your answer and compare to mine and see if there is any noticeable runtime difference.

I believe Ive figured out a working solution.

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include "command.h"
#include "builtins.h"
#include "shell.h"
#include "common.h"
#include "bashgetopt.h"
#include "xmalloc.h"

#ifdef HAVE_CONFIG_H
#include <config.h>
#endif

#ifndef errno
extern int errno;
#endif

// Function declaration for our builtin
static int lseek_main(int argc, char **argv);
int lseek_builtin(WORD_LIST *list);
extern char **make_builtin_argv();

// Metadata about the builtin
static char *lseek_doc[] = {
    "",
    "----------------------------------------------",
    "USAGE:    lseek <FD> <REL_OFFSET>",
    "",
    "Move the file descriptor <FD> by <REL_OFFSET>",
    "bytes relative to its current byte offset.",
    "",
    "positive <REL_OFFSET> advances the <FD>",
    "negative <REL_OFFSET> rewinds the <FD>",
    "----------------------------------------------",
    "",
    NULL
};

// Struct to register the builtin with bash
struct builtin lseek_struct = {
    "lseek",              // Name of the builtin
    lseek_builtin,        // Function to call
    BUILTIN_ENABLED,      // Default status
    lseek_doc,            // Documentation strings
    "lseek <FD> <REL_OFFSET>",  // Usage string
    0                     // Number of long options
};

// main function
static int lseek_main(int argc, char **argv) {
    // check for exactly 2 args passed to lseek
    if (argc != 3) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nIncorrect number of arguments.\nUSAGE: lseek <FD> <REL_OFFSET>\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // get + validate file descriptor
    int fd = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (fd == 0 && strcmp(argv[1], "0") != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nERROR: Invalid file descriptor.\n");
        return 1;
    }

     // get + validate (relative) offset
    errno = 0;
    off_t offset = atoll(argv[2]);
    if (errno == ERANGE) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nERROR: Offset out of range.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // call lseek to move fd byte offset 
    if (lseek(fd, offset, SEEK_CUR) == (off_t) -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nERROR: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}

// func to convert WORD_LIST to argc + argv 
// (this one is called by the builtin)
int lseek_builtin(WORD_LIST *list) {
    int c, r;
    char **v;

    v = make_builtin_argv(list, &c);
    r = lseek_main(c, v);
    xfree(v);

    return r;
}


hi @jkool702, this is not how this site works. your "answer" has nothing to do with the segfault in your question. if you have a different implementation which has different issues please ask a different question.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
